# Why my MA plot shows a pattern/trend while the normalized expression values not?

Tags: r, microarray

I am doing microarray analysis using bioconductor. I first performed the quality checks which was ok according to recommendations. I created an MA plot after normalizing the AffyBatch data.  My MA plot looks as follows:

```
mva.pairs(exprs(myEset),col=2:7)
```

[image: MA plot after normalization]

Then after, I performed fit using the following commands.

```
library(limma)
Group<- factor(pData(ABatch)[,'group'] , levels = levels(pData(ABatch)[,'group']))
design<- model.matrix(~Group)
fit <-lmFit(myEset,design)
fit<-eBayes(fit)  
top.all <- topTable(fit,n=nrow(exprs(myEset)),adjust="BH",coef=2)
```

Now again I am trying to create MA plot from `top.all` define above using following commands

```
M <- top.all$logFC #log fold-change
A <- top.all$AveExpr # ave. expr. level
mat <- cbind(A,M)           
plotMA(mat,main="MA plot")                   
abline(h=3,col="red")
```

I get the following plot

[image: MA plot after fit]

Now, I am not sure why the second plot is showing a pattern (fold-change increases as the avg. expression increases). Is there any problem in the analysis here?

Comment: The first call to mva.pairs is conventional. We compare each array to a reference array (synthetic in some versions). The difference between each array and this reference should not depend on avg expression. I am not familiar with the second version. You have computed a fold-change based on a phenotype. Is there any expectation that this should not relate to avg expression?

Comment: @julieth, thanks for reply. The first figure should not show any dependance. There is no any expectation of any such trend, but I was wondering if this is normal to have plots with some trend after fitting to linear model.